# QListWidget very long text

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I'm asking this question because i dont know how to google it, i dont find the right keywords.

I have a **QListWidget** with strings inside. The strings are very long and if i disable horizontal scrolling, which is what i want, then the text ends with ... because it is too long.

I would like to have the text to display the end of the text and the beginning like:

**This is very long text** to **This is ... text** instead of **This is very long ...**

Is there any simple way to achieve this without having to manipulate the string? I need the full string afterwards and i dont want to store extra data. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed a very easy solution: Lock for `TextElideMode` and `Qt::ElideMiddle` (`setTextElideMode ( Qt::TextElideMode mode )`).

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what i meant, i knew there was an easy way but i didnt know the exact words :) Thanks +1